# How to make TextView in Android bolder than the default bold?

Tags: android

As you already know, we can make a TextView bold by the textStyle attribute in XML. However, the default bold is not enough. How could I make it bolder?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this style

```
style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
```

or if that isn't enough

```
style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
```

then set your text style to

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the font family instead of textStyle

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"           // roboto regular
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     // roboto light
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" // roboto condensed
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"     // roboto black
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"      // roboto thin (android 4.2)
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"    // roboto medium (android 5.0)
```

for your case try

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
```

if this is not enough you can apply textStyle on font family black

[image: Font families sample]